# Update post meta array - add new, single value

Tags: post-meta, meta-value

What i'm trying to do - i have meta field in post with array of user emails, i'd like to add new user email(if it's not there already) with each submission of Contact form 7.

Here's what i managed to do by now:

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent',
    function ($contact_form) {
        if ($contact_form->id() === 32009) {
            $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
            //$currentdata = get_post_meta(32127, 'customer_email');
            $mail = $submission->get_posted_data('email-002');
            update_post_meta(32127, 'customer_email',$mail);
        }
    }
);
```

Thing is that above code is replacing whole array with one new string and i just want to add it, not replace whole thing.

**add_post_meta** create duplicates and with unique="true" it doesn't add anything.

I would appreciate if anyone could explain to me how can i achieve what i need and maybe a little about updating meta fields, since reading wordpress documentation doesn't really answer my questions.

Comment: post meta values are just strings, even if you try to store an array it gets flattened to a string. `update_post_meta` replaces the entire value it can't edit/append as it has no concept of "structured data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close. In my code I've assumed that the desired `customer_email` meta looks like this:

```
array(
    0 => 'joe@example.com',
    1 => 'sue@example.com',
    2 => 'thehamburglar@example.com',
);
```

What you need to do is add the *new* email address to the array of *existing* email addresses, then save the updated array back to the meta value. `update_post_meta()` simply overwrites whatever's already in the meta value, so you can't use it to simply merge a new value into an existing array.

Something like this should do it:

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent',
    function ($contact_form) {
        if ($contact_form->id() === 32009) {
            $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
            $currentdata = get_post_meta(32127, 'customer_email', true);
            if ( empty( $currentdata ) ) {
                $currentdata = array();
            }
            // Bail out if $currentdata *isn't* an array.
            if ( ! is_array( $currentdata ) ) {
                return;
            }
            $mail = $submission->get_posted_data('email-002');
            // Add the new email address to $currentdata.
            $currentdata[] = $mail;
            update_post_meta(32127, 'customer_email',$currentdata);
        }
    }
);
```

**Edited:** I've changed `get_post_meta( 32127, 'customer_email' );` to `get_post_meta( 32127, 'customer_email', true );` to ensure that we only get a single post_meta value. Otherwise it will grab all the post_meta values with the key `customer_email`.

I'm not sure that's the cause of the error you're seeing in the comments, but it should make the code more precise.

Comment: can you expand a bit on what you did? The solution is in your code but it's buried a bit

Comment: with above code when trying to add duplicate i'm getting PHP error:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: strtolower(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given
- is it that something is not sanitized properly?

Comment: I've updated the code; I'm not sure that's the fix, but it'll improve the precision.

Comment: @PatJ thanks! now it works properly. At the end of the script i have added a little check for duplicates: if (in_array($mail, $currentdata)) {
                return;
            } else {
                $currentdata[] = $mail;
                update_post_meta(32127, 'customer_email',$currentdata);
            }
and now it's perfect, thanks again!